# Cannot apply Operator '<' to operands of type T and T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

so here's my code

```
public void BubbleSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[j - 1])
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and before you shoot be down for not searching. I have searched and one of the answers here on SO said to use an icomparable interface to solve the problem.

unfortunately i am not going anywhere with this error.

Answer (score 23):

It looks like you're expecting the `IComparable<T>` constraint to allow you to use an inequality operator. `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` say *nothing* about using inequality operators directly. Instead, what they do are provide a `CompareTo()` method you can use to *simulate* the inequality operators:

```
public void BubbleSort<T>(T[] array) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            if (array[j].CompareTo(array[j-1]) < 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you can't add a generic constraint, then [`Comparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
```

is very useful. You can then use `comparer.Compare(x,y)` (and check the result for negative, zero, positive); this supports types that implement `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`, included "lifted" support for `Nullable<T>` wrappers - and will avoid boxing for the struct and `Nullable<T>` cases when the type supports `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Are you saying x.CompareTo(y) is not as efficient as  Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x,y) for some types?

Comment: @crokusek I'm saying it isn't as efficient *for some scenarios involving generics*, specifically when you don't have the `T : IComparable<T>` constraint that would be required to allow "constrained call". If you *cast* to `IComparable<T>` / `IComparable` rather than using the `T : IComparable<T>` constraint, it will impose a box + virtual call, which is much more expensive than a constrained call. `Comparer<T>.Default` uses some tricks to ensure that it *does* use a constrained call whenever possible, only using box + virtual call as a fallback if that isn't possible.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use operators on generic types.

Instead, you need to use the `CompareTo()` method from `IComparable<T>`:

```
if (array[j].CompareTo(array[j - 1]) < 0)
```

Beware of `null`s.

Answer (score 3):

Hence you declare `T` as `IComparable`, use its [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
 if (array[j].CompareTo(array[j-1]) < 0)
 {

 }
```